# Regex concat with "AND" opeartor

Tags: regex, regex-group

I want to concatenate two Regular expressions with AND operator (I don't know if this is possible ... ) so the match happens only when the string matches RegEx1 and RegEx2.

```
 RegEx1: [a-g]+
 RegEx2: [b-z]+
 Example1 : String "bcd" match 
 Example2 : String "hijk" not match
```

It was easy with OR operator, but for AND I could not find a solution.

Comment: What language/tool are you using? Does your regex flavour accept lookahead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a positive lookahead combined with 'start and end of string' anchors to ensure entire string is matched and no "illegal" letters are present:

```
^(?=[a-g]+$)(?=[b-z]+$).*
```

https://regex101.com/r/Bz7qnb/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the positive look-ahead operator `(?=)` to combine expressions:

```
(?=[a-g]+)(?=[b-z]+)
```

Here is a fiddle to test it: https://regex101.com/r/kyy6XZ/1

In this case, it's logically equivalent to `[b-g]+`, which means it should match any string that has a letter or more in the `b` to `g` interval, boundaries included.

Comment: This is matching `bijk` but I don't think it should.

Comment: `b` is between `a` and `g` and between `b` and `z`, so yeah it matches both expressions that requires at least one letter in their interval, doesn't it?

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat I think the OP wants it anchored, something like: `\b(?=[a-g]+\b)(?=[b-z]+\b)[a-z]+\b`

Comment: @AdrienBrunelat it doesn't match `bijk` with my pattern above using word boundaries: see [here](https://regex101.com/r/1suJUG/1)